# When is it appropriate to neglect all terms after the first non-zero term of a Taylor expansion series?

Tags: fourier-analysis, taylor-expansion, fourier-series, bessel-functions

Suppose I am interested in the Taylor expansion series of a Cosine function at the neighbourhood of a=0.
In computing the series from n=0 to n = infinity, when would it be appropriate to neglect all terms after the first non-zero term?

This is in regard to Bessel's equation

Comment: I think you need to add more context about your motivation for truncating the Taylor's series. Having said that, the percent error for the first term for cosine, namely $1$, is $x$ for $-\pi/2 \lt x \lt \pi/2$ (keep in mind my literal interpretation is due to not knowing any context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for $\cos(x)$, this is usually done when the argument $x$ is small compared with unity.  Just how small depends on how accurate you would like your results.

The "quick and dirty" way to know if it's good enough, is to compare the error directly with evaluation of $\cos(x)$.

Comment: What is unity defined as in this context?

Comment: The value 1, but you could also probably say it should be small compared with $pi$ or something... but honestly there's no rules here, and it depends on context.  Evaluating the error between your series and cos(x), or maybe the function that depends on these will give you more intuition I think.